# Java equivalent of System.Drawing.Color.Empty

Tags: java, colors

.NET has System.Drawing.Color.Empty. But, what is Java equivalent of System.Drawing.Color.Empty?

Answer (score 1):

Specifying all zeroes to java.awt.Color works for me. For example:

```
new java.awt.Color(0, true)
```

Or

```
new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the color to `null` in Java.

`Color.Empty` exists because in C# `Color` is a value-type that cannot be null.